# MySQL stored procedure syntax error: if else

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error

I have a MySQL db, and I want to write a query containing IF ELSE statements.  Originally, I tried using IF ELSE by itself, but after failing repeatedly to get it to work, I read that IF ELSE statements in MySQL must be inside stored procedures.  However, I am unable to create a stored procedure without a syntax error.  Here's a very simple example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getUsers()
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM users;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The specific error message I get is:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE getUsers()
  BEGIN
    select * from users;
  END' at line 1

I have read numerous other posts related to this issue, but none of the fixes suggested seem to work for my case (specifically, adding the delimiter).  What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, after hours of trying to figure this one out, I happened to find an answer right after posting my question.  I needed to remove the 
`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getUsers()` and replace it with

`DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS getUsers;
...
CREATE PROCEDURE getUsers()`